# Activate "Reopen Windows When Logging Back In"

Tags: macos, macbook, reboot, osx-yosemite, session-restore

I got OSX **Yosemite 10.2.2** and even when I **Check** `Reopen Windows When Logging Back In` before shutdown then when I start my last windows are not reopened. How to solve this please ?

Comment: Make sure to uncheck the box in 
`System Preferences` -> `General` -> `Close windows when quitting an app`

Comment: @chesh this worked but I've noticed that firefox doesn't reopen last session

Comment: maybe this is the same behaviour you observed with Mac OSX. Have you checked that, in Firefox's [preferences menu](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2014-03-21-13-30-01-8633dd.png), the `Show my windows and tabs from last time` option is selected ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close SO's post, I'll convert my comment into an answer.

Make sure to uncheck the box in `System Preferences` -> `General` -> `Close windows when quitting an app`.